# Integrate Saxon-PE in Camel using camel-saxon

Tags: apache-camel, saxon

I use Camel 2.22.1 with springboot 2.0.4.RELEASE. The camel component `camel-saxon` use default Saxon-HE. I have some Xquery files, which call Java method, so I want to replace Saxon-HE with Saxon-PE. I requested one test license for Saxon-PE and tried different ways and didn't get it work. The Saxon-PE jar file `saxon9pe.jar` is already loaded, however, **it is still working as Saxon HE edition**. I guess, the license is not correctly loaded by Saxon-PE.

I tried following ways, none of them has worked.

- put license file `saxon-license.lic` and `saxon9pe.jar` in the same folder
- define an environment variable SAXON_HOME, and put `saxon-license.lic` and `saxonpe.jar` in SAXON_HOME\bin
- modify `org.apache.camel.component.xquery.XQueryBuilder.configuration` in class `XqueryBuild.java` in package `org.apache.camel.component.xquery` to set `LICENSE_FILE_LOCATION` ( I got Error: Unknown configuration property http://saxon.sf.net/feature/licenseFileLocation)

The Saxon Documentation mentioned to create an XML configuration file, but I don't know where should I put this XML configuration file.

When running an Xquery with Java call I got the error:

`Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Cannot find a 0-argument function named Q{java:java.lang.Double}MAX_VALUE(). Reflexive calls to Java methods are not available under Saxon-HE at net.sf.saxon.query.UnboundFunctionLibrary.bindUnboundFunctionReferences(UnboundFunctionLibrary.java:166) ~[saxon9pe.jar!/:na]
at net.sf.saxon.query.QueryModule.bindUnboundFunctionCalls(QueryModule.java:1172) ~[saxon9pe.jar!/:na]
 at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Executable.fixupQueryModules(Executable.java:462) ~[saxon9pe.jar!/:na]
at net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.makeXQueryExpression(XQueryParser.java:176) ~[saxon9pe.jar!/:na]
at  net.sf.saxon.query.StaticQueryContext.compileQuery(StaticQueryContext.java:597) ~[saxon9pe.jar!/:na]
at  net.sf.saxon.query.StaticQueryContext.compileQuery(StaticQueryContext.java:658) ~[saxon9pe.jar!/:na]
at  org.apache.camel.component.xquery.XQueryBuilder$3.createQueryExpression(XQueryBuilder.java:276) ~[classes!/:2.23.1]
at  org.apache.camel.component.xquery.XQueryBuilder.initialize(XQueryBuilder.java:745) ~[classes!/:2.23.1]
at  org.apache.camel.component.xquery.XQueryBuilder.evaluateAsDOM(XQueryBuilder.java:190) ~[classes!/:2.23.1]
at org.apache.camel.component.xquery.XQueryBuilder.evaluate(XQueryBuilder.java:151) ~[classes!/:2.23.1]
... 40 common frames omitted`

Can some share some experience with setting up Saxon-PE with camel to get calling Java working within Xquery?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be useful to know how it fails. Specifically, we need to establish whether it is finding the Saxon-PE jar file and attempting to execute it (but failing), or whether it is failing to find the Saxon-PE jar file. Knowlng the symptoms would help to distinguish between those two cases.

Comment: Note that the question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34599874/using-saxon-pe-with-apache-camel-error-pre-loading-saxon-classes and some SO members might therefore be inclined to close it as a duplicate; I'm reluctant to do that because the answer may well have changed since 2016.

Comment: If a Xquery doesn't require a feature in Saxon PE, then everything is fine. If  fails when I try to execute an Xquery, where there is call to Java method. Even with the simple example from saxon documentation `<a xmlns:double="java:java.lang.Double">  {double:MAX_VALUE()} </a>`

Comment: The error when running an Xquery with Java call is:
`Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Cannot find a 0-argument function named Q{java:java.lang.Double}MAX_VALUE(). Reflexive calls to Java methods are not available under Saxon-HE
        at net.sf.saxon.query.UnboundFunctionLibrary.bindUnboundFunctionReferences(UnboundFunctionLibrary.java:166) ~[saxon9pe.jar!/:na]`

I'm sure that `saxon9pe.jar` is loaded and used und believe, that it behave as Saxon HE, because the license is not correctly loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the extra information supplied, it looks as if you're picking up the Saxon JAR file but not the license file.

Putting the license file in the same folder as the JAR file is often enough, but it only works with some classloaders.

In general you either need to ensure that the directory containing the JAR file is on the classpath, or you need to (somehow) set Saxon's configuration property LICENSE_FILE_LOCATION.

According to https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-saxon/src/main/docs/xquery-component.adoc, you can set Saxon configuration properties using `configuration` and `configurationProperties`, but I don't see any further explanation of how this works. I'll have a dig around.

Comment: You are right, putting license file and JAR file in the the same folder works only with **some** classloeders. And I use classloader provided by Spring and it doesn't work. 
I have tried to set  Saxon's configuration property `LICENSE_FILE_LOCATION`. 

if (configuration == null) {
               configuration = new Configuration();
               configuration.setConfigurationProperty(Feature.LICENSE_FILE_LOCATION, "path2LicenseFile");
}
But I got the error:
Error: Unknown configuration property http://saxon.sf.net/feature/licenseFileLocation

Comment: You need `new ProfessionalConfiguration()` rather than `new Configuration()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I should use `ProfessionalConfiguration()` instead of `Configuration()`.